# Error to deploy my Vue3 app to Github Pages

Tags: vue.js, github, vuejs2, vuejs3, github-pages

I have uploaded my project with Vue3 to Github pages ([check my repository](https://github.com/amoralesdesign/pokevue)), the branch is assigned to gh-pages and I have also uploaded the **/dist** folder, generated with the:
**npm run build** command.

I also modified the **vue.config.js** file with this data from my repository:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/pokevue/" : "/"
})
```

I have two questions:

The first is why isn't Vue working/loading [in my web](https://amoralesdesign.github.io/pokevue/), if I followed the instructions in this [guide](https://learnvue.co/2020/09/how-to-deploy-your-vue-app-to-github-pages/#step-4-run-git-subtree-push-prefix-dist-origin-gh-pages) correctly.

The second one is why this route does not show the "home" (it is broken, of course):
https://amoralesdesign.github.io/pokevue/

But when you click on the Pokémon logo it does redirect to my real Home, although if you reload the page it gives a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You need to config your base router points to your github page path:

```js
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/pokevue/' : '/'),
    routes
})
```

The reason when you click on the logo your home page is showing is that in that case, the vue router will match your URL with the home page route.